# nohup as background task does NOT return prompt

Tags: nohup

I am trying to run a long running task in the background without having to be logged in and have the terminal return a prompt, but when I do this, the task appears to go into the background, but my prompt does not become available unless I hit control + c. I want to run the task and then get my prompt back.

```
[staging@php-pos-web ~]$ nohup php test.php > test.txt &
[1] 27251
[staging@php-pos-web ~]$ nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should have your prompt available because your command will be sent to the background.  It is possible that you are not seeing your prompt because your command is still delivering stderr messages to your console.  Try using `> test.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &`.

Comment: That seems to work, but there is one more error. In the output file (test.txt) the following line is in there before the script output. `nohup: ignoring input`

Comment: You can redirect input from /dev/null to get rid of this message: `> test.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &`

Comment: The lesson for me was that there is both output and input that the shell waits on so you have to redirect both. Thanks!