# Return prompt after accessing nohup.out (bash)

Tags: python, bash, shell, nohup

I'm running a Python script from bash using `nohup`. The script is executed via my bashrc as part of a shell function. If I run it like this:

```
function timer { 
    nohup python path/timer.py $1 $2 > path/nohup.out 2>&1 &
    echo 'blah'
}
```

Everything works and I get my prompt back. However, if instead of `echo` I call `tail` to access the end of the nohup output file, like this:

```
function timer { 
    nohup python path/timer.py $1 $2 > path/nohup.out 2>&1 &
    tail -f path/nohup.out
}
```

my prompt is not returned. I would like to see the contents of nohup.out and get back to the prompt without having to use CTRL-c.

I have followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024850/nohup-as-background-task-does-not-return-prompt), but adding `</dev/null` yields the same results as above.

Comment: See: `man tail`

Comment: tail -f doesn't exit unless it gets a SIGHUP/SIGINT/etc signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get prompt.

Because, `tail -f` will always watch the file (`path/nohup.out`) to output appended data as the file grows. You can try `tail -n` to get last `10` lines of `path/nohup.out`.

Comment: Thanks.  At first, `tail -n` or `tail --lines` didn't cut it, because the file was being read before the relevant information had been written to it.  I'm working around this with `sleep 1s`, followed by `tail`, but it would be cleaner to just watch the file until it's written.  Is there a way to terminate `tail -f` with a subsequent call (i.e. not ctrl-c)?  I've tried several variants of `kill $!`.